# Android - Реализация сворачивания фрагмента/ативности на фоне другой активности, как видео на ютуб

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Идея такова, у меня сейчас есть активность 
[image: Окно которое надо сворачивать]

Ее надо свернуть но не закрывать и если она свернута отображать поверх всех окон иконку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что бы при нажатии на нее я смог опять попасть на это активити (Это нужно если сильно долгая загрузка на сервер, что бы не ждать пока загрузка пройдет, а лазить по приложению или просматривать стену, или открывать планы).

Пример я видел в ютуб приложении. Когда смотришь видео и свайпашь вниз то снизу элемент поверх всех окон при нажатии на который ты опять открываешь это видео.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел уже готовую библиотеку, хорошо подошла для меня
https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel

Answer (score 0):

Эффект когда вам кажется что активити показывается над другим активити можно имитировать используя анимацию: 
Start an activity with a shared element
https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity#start-with-element

Comment: Спасибо, хороший совет по анимации перехода, а как сделать например вью которая будут появляться если мы вернулись обратно на актиквити, но не закрыли предыдущее для вывыплнения фоновых задач, то есть по стаку активити мы вернулись обратно но при нажатии мы не вызываем новое а открываем по стаку следующее незакрытое? У вас есть какие то мысли о этому поводу?

Comment: Думаю вам стоит вставить в ваш Presenter или общую модель какой то объект который хранит состояние связанное с жизненным циклом активити, т.е. что-то сохранять туда на OnStop, OnDestroy и т.д. Но вообще опять же Google всячески продвиает модель - Одна активит и все внутри это либо фрагменты, либо это полностью ваши группы View.